# Visual Studio 2013 Community with Update 4 on Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 10074

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013

I today upgraded to Windows 10 Build 10074 that I downloaded from here. Now, I wanted to develop apps for Windows and Windows Phone as a Universal app. Also that I'm willing to do the same for Android devices therefore, I downloaded Visual Studio Community 2013 with Update 4 from here. Now, after it installed it first gave a warning that the system doesn't support Windows Phone 8 emulator (and I understand this because I suppose the processor, Core 2 Duo E7000 doesn't support visualization/SLAT technology). After this I opened Visual Studio which first loaded, then closed automatically (quite abruptly). I opened a sample solution afterward which loaded, then a dialog came stating you need to enable developer mode in Windows 10 under Settings>Update and Security>For Developers but when I went there and clicked For Developers, the window closed (similar to Visual Studio).

How do I enable it then? And I don't know should I re-install/uninstall it? Or maybe I should download Visual Studio 2015 RC?

Thanks,

Kvaibhav01.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the settings window closing when I choose "for developers".   I think that's the heart of your question, is that right?

Comment: Yup, that's the "heart" of the question. Plus, VS2013 Community also closes abruptly in this build!

Comment: Please check answer on question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249551/enabling-developer-mode-on-windows-10-build-build-10074#

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to develop for the new universal app Platform, you will need VS2015 RC, but your apps won't work on Windows 8 devices, only for Windows 10.

Comment: That means, VS2013 will not run on Build 10074? and why not the 'For Developers' window is opening?

Comment: VS2013 will run on Build 10074, but you can't create a  UAP app with VS2013, only with 2015 RC. I have no idea why the "For developper" window is not opening... I have the same problem on my side

Comment: But on my machine VS2013 Community just opens and then the window closes automatically. Any idea why?

Comment: I've posted the same query in the MSDN forums ...you can see it here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/468bb8e8-36ba-46c3-ae1c-2e358a57534a/visual-studio-2013-community-with-update-4-on-windows-10-insider-preview-build-10074?forum=vssetup