# Enabling developer mode on Windows 10 Build build 10074

Tags: windows

Windows 10 Insider Preview build 10074 has a known issue using the Settings application to enable developer mode.   In this build, if you try Settings/Update & Security/For developers... the settings window suddenly closes.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's a work-around.  In an administrator command prompt, type the following commands:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock" /t REG_DWORD /f /v "AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense" /d "1"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock" /t REG_DWORD /f /v "AllowAllTrustedApps" /d "1"
```

Then reboot the machine to enable developer mode